# IDE for highlighting html written inside javascript

Tags: javascript, templates, ide, aptana, sublimetext3

I'm generating my html on clientside by writing html in javascript. My template file is pretty big, some 900 lines of continuous code. Every part in the script renders different part of html.

However my IDE doesnt highlights/color-code html code when written inside javascript single quotes. So debugging/develeopment is pretty difficult. If only this html could be color highlighted better inside

Update:
Reworded Query: I'm generating my html at clientside within javascript. Which means that my html is written inside javascript single quotes which gets inerted into the dom. This html within javascript is not highlighted by my IDE. I looking if there is a way

Comment: use event listeners instead of inline events?

Comment: @dandavis How can that help? could you explain.

Comment: it means you can get the js out of the html, where it can live in full-color whitespace aplenty splendor, as well as work better, be more maintainable, and easier to DRY.

Comment: @dandavis Maybe I was not clear but I'm generating my html at clientside within javascript. Which means that my html is written inside javascript single quotes which gets inerted into the dom. This html within javascript is not highlighted by my IDE. I looking if there is a way.

Comment: oh yeah, i had it backwards, my bad. you can use a <template> tag to store the html as un-escaped strings in an html context, which means they should get highlighted. you could also keep them in a separate file which you load via ajax, and that small file would be highlighted correctly as well. now that FF keep JS comments, you can keep un-escaped HTML in JS function comments, which can be fetched via fn.toString(). ex: alert(function(){/* <html> <here>  */}); if those will highlight, who knows...

Answer (score 0):

[WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) can do this.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]